# Sort ListView elements in ascending order using Adapter

Tags: android, sorting, listview

In my app, my goal is for the user to upload an image from their gallery, and save it in a database. Each image will have a name and that name and image will be displayed in a listview. The listviews will be sorted kind of like contacts in a phone. What they are exactly are maps of properties, such as different hotels or resorts, or even schools, for the purpose of delivering. I have everything working the way that I want, but for some reason I'm having trouble getting them into alphabetical order. I've tried other examples and snippets, but with no luck. The code I have for it is as follows:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_hotels);

    db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
    pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic);
    fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt1);

    final ArrayList<Hotel> hotels = new ArrayList<>(db.getAllHotels());
    data = new dataAdapter(this, hotels);

    Collections.sort(hotels, new Comparator<Hotel>()
    {
        public int compare(Hotel a1, Hotel a2)
        {
            return (a1.toString()).compareTo(a2.toString());
        }
    });

    lv.setAdapter(data);
}
```

Before I put the code in for the comparisons:

```
Collections.sort(hotels, new Comparator<Hotel>()
    {
        public int compare(Hotel a1, Hotel a2)
        {
            return (a1.toString()).compareTo(a2.toString());
        }
    });
```

It would simply display the images in the order that they were saved. But with this chunk of code, it seems that something is wrong. I tried saving 3 different images of properties: Westgate Resort, Grand Country Inn, and College of the Ozarks, in that order. And for some reason, Westgate was shown first, College of the Ozarks second, and Grand Country Inn third. If I add the same image and name it Grand Country Inn as well, Westgate Resort will fall to the bottom of the list. Which seems correct, but upon adding another image, Westgate will go back to the top. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time.

Comment: you are trying to compare the .toString() of an hotel object. instead you should have an attribute in the hotel object lets say imagestring and compare them to make it right. Like this if you did not override a tostring function that gives this string, it is normal to encounter problems when you cast it to string directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. Instead of using the Collections.sort() method, I just used sort() on my adapter.

```
data = new dataAdapter(this, hotels);

    data.sort(new Comparator<Hotel>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Hotel arg0, Hotel arg1)
        {
            return arg0.getFName().compareTo(arg1.getFName());
        }
    });

    data.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lv.setAdapter(data);
```

I'm not sure if it's bad practice or not, but for what I want, it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the adapter after you call the **sort** method.

Answer (score 0):

Please do consider adding

```
data.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

each time you add an element into the list.

Another thing that you can do is to lower case each element before adding them into the list. Or try this code

```
Collections.sort(hotels, new Comparator<Hotel>(){
    public int compare(Hotel a1, Hotel a2)
    {
        return (a1.toString().toLowerCase()).compareTo(a2.toString().toLowerCase());
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmm. I tried this solution, but had no luck unfortunately. Each time I click on my display button, the outputs are different. Each element seems to move up the list each time, resulting in a different output each time.

Comment: Ok, have you tried sorting before calling data = new dataAdapter(this, hotels);?

Comment: That causes the app to crash when I click the button to display the results. But unfortunately, doesn't give any errors in logcat.